# BashScript stopps/ never finishes without any errormessage

Tags: node.js, bash, postgresql

when i try to run a bashscript in GIT BASH (working on a Windows OS) to execute psql commands i get the following result:

```
name@DESKTOP-AVB2MRC MINGW64 ~/dragonstack/backend
a npm run configure

> backend@1.0.0 configure C:\Users\name\dragonstack\backend
>  bash ./bin/configure_db.sh

Configuring dragonstackdb
```

My Files:

configure_db.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Configuring dragonstackdb";

dropdb -U node_user dragonstackdb;
createdb -U node_user dragonstackdb;

psql -U node_user dragonstackdb <./bin/sql/generation.sql;
psql -U node_user dragonstackdb <./bin/sql/dragon.sql;

echo "dragonstackdb configured";
```

generation.sql

```
CREATE TABLE generation(
    id         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
    expiration TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

dragon.sql

```
CREATE TABLE dragon(
    id             SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    birthdate      TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    nickname       VARCHAR(64),
    "generationId" INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY ("generationId") REFERENCES generation(id)
);
```

Comment: What happens if you use `-f` instead of redirecting input from the `.sql` files?  The reason I ask is because your files make no attempt to exit `psql`, so your script is probably sitting at a `psql` prompt after `generation` is created.

Comment: Still the same, the dropdb command doesnt work properly for some reason. It should ask for user password..